# Range wiring - - reposting to add pictures please help thanks

Tags: wiring, range

I have not been able to find anyone that has the issue that I do. I’ll quickly summarize I bought a range for powder coating without a power cord. I assume it was an older 3prong originally . I have a receptacle for a welding machine which has three prongs and has the two vertical polarized flat plugs in relation to the Small one.NOT the angled 3 prong plug. Can I wire this cord that I have that’s actually for welding directly to the stove? it is six gauge wire I think stoves are usually eight??, so I’m just looking for some guidance here on if I can take the cut end in the picture and direct wire to stove.I know there’s a white, black and green wire on the on the cut end. Where do they go? I’m just not sure if that will work or not in relation to the red white and black connectors on the range.. Any help is so greatly appreciate it.
It  is a 50amp recepticle and a 50 amp breaker. Installed 2 years ago

wiringra[image: wire]

[image: rewire]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not really.  The range requires two hots, a neutral, and should have a ground.  You want a NEMA 14 type plug/receptacle of the right ampage.  The welder is using a NEMA 6 type.  The welder can use a nema 14 type plug with the white wire not connected, but doubt if the range will work right without the white connected.

Comment: Can you post photos of the range's wiring diagram please, or at least a make and model number?

Comment: With the range wiring diagram or make/model, someone might be able to say the range neutral is not needed, if so that welding plug might work, with black to black, white to red, and ground to steel.

Comment: I will get the wiring diagrm model number etc.

Comment: CRIP659 are you saying the green wire to the frame of the oven? I just want to make sure I understand you correctly.